# DIV appear on scroll up control position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a DIV bar that appears on bottom of screen upon load, disappears when user scrolls down and reappears when user is back at top. I would like to control when the DIV starts to reappear when scrolling back up. How can I make this happen?

HTML

```
<div id="bottom-cta">
  <a href="/join">Get Started!</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#bottom-cta {
  background-color: #3bb618;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 0 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  height: 60px;
  transition: bottom 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: bottom 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: bottom 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -otransition: bottom 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
#bottom-cta a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

jQuery

```
var $element = $('#bottom-cta');

$(window).scroll(function() {

if($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $element.fadeOut();
} else {
    $element.fadeIn();
}
});
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6usogk7z/

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: `if($(this).scrollTop() > 0)` here is the place where magic happens. Just play around with 0

Comment: `if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 )` means if we are 0 pixels from the top, run some code. That's how you control it.

Comment: @JSEvgeny this works but it is controlling when it disappears on scroll down, how can I control the scroll up position where it re-apopears?

Comment: @ChrisHappy this works but it is controlling when it disappears on scroll down, how can I control the scroll up position where it re-apopears?

Comment: It controls both up and down.

Comment: @hev1 hide DIV on scroll down, show on scroll up

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `window`'s current scroll position in a variable and check if the `window`'s scroll position when it is scrolled is more than it (user is scrolling down) to hide the footer and otherwise show the footer (since the user is scrolling up).

```js
var $element = $('#bottom-cta');
var prevYPos = $(window).scrollTop();//current window scroll position
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentYPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(currentYPos > prevYPos) {
        $element.fadeOut();
    } else {
        $element.fadeIn(0);
    }
    prevYPos = currentYPos;//set the previous scroll position to the scroll position when the window is scrolled
});
```

```css
#bottom-cta {
background-color: #3bb618;
text-align: center;
padding: 11px 0 11px;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
height: 60px;
transition: bottom 0.1s ease-in-out;


}
#bottom-cta a {
color: #fff;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: 700;
display: inline-block;
}

body { 
height: 2000px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bottom-cta">
<a href="/join">Get Started!</a>
</div>
```